# How to log messages in GAE go runtime?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am using the following simple code snippet to log messages in my [application](https://github.com/usmanismail/klaxon) and during local testing I see all my logs.

However, I do not see any application logs when I deploy the app to GAE. Do I need to set logging properties anywhere? Or am I using the wrong logging library?

```
import (
    "log"
)

func Info(logMessage string, v ...interface{}) {
    if v != nil {
        log.Printf("[INFO]  "+logMessage, v)
    } else {
        log.Printf("[INFO]  " + logMessage)
    }
}
```

Comment: On a tangent, `Info` is using variadics incorrectly. There is no need to check for `nil` and the `v` parameter should be expanded like `v...`. [play.golang.org/p/XGu2fSizKg](http://play.golang.org/p/XGu2fSizKg)

Comment: Thank you, I am a total noob to go so knowledge dump is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the app engine logging provided with the [`Context` interface](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#Context).
It provides several `Debugf`, `Infof`, `Warningf`, `Errorf`, and `Criticalf`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to deft_code 's answer:

The log will appear in the GAE console's log and color coded.

And I give you 2 lines of sample to start with:

```
appContext := appengine.NewContext(httpRequest)
appContext.Errorf("Couldn't send email: %v", err)
```